# how to programmatically access iphone browser history

Tags: iphone, browser-history

is it any way to access the iphone's browser history(safari) programatically

thanks

Comment: God, I hope not.  I don't want some random app knowing what web sites I've been browsing.

Comment: Agreed with Paul. If there is a way to do so, this may cause privacy issues. I think currently there is no way to do so, in future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing that, as safari's files are not accessible from other application and there are no API ala AdressBook.