# iOS - Retrieve the most visited websites on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a mobile app in objective-c for iOS.

Is there a way inside my app to programmatically retrieve the most visited websites from the browsers on the device?
I am interested in the urls specifically (e.g. "http://www.google.com"), in order to check a couple of things.

I've searched online but I haven't find anything that could satisfy these needs: does every browser save this kind of information in a private folder not accessible to anyone else and so it's not possible to get this data? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks anyway for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the developed applications are sandboxed. You can't access data out of one app from another. It's part of the security model.

Apple didn't published APIs for this privacy access level, It only published the following APIs for Safari extensions:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions

BTW, This question is asked alot before, you can check them:

> [how to programmatically access iphone browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904704/how-to-programmatically-access-iphone-browser-history)
>
> [How to access iPhone Safari History in an App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093703/how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: No, it's impossible. Apple doesn't give as an API to do that.